# Amazon SES, The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: iis-7, amazon-ses

It was working fine when tested on the local SMTP but when deployed over the Amazon web server  getting the following exception.

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.The server response was: Authentication required

After going through so many blogs and posts it seems I should complete two steps to make it work.

1. enableSsl="true" in webconfig
2. second to install certificate on the app in IIS, we didn't buy the certificate so for testing I do the same as per the Scott Gu
    [Enabling SSL on IIS 7.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx)

My web config entry is as below

```
 <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="behindthecurtain@empowher.com">
    <network host="email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" userName="xxxx" password="xxxx" port="587"
       defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true"/>
  </smtp>
```

So what else we can do to make it working ? guys any idea I'm totally stuck as you guess.

Comment: how should I proceed? any idea?

Comment: You don't need to install a cert on your webserver as you are the client when connecting to the smtp server. Show the code you are using to send the email.